# PowerShell: How to [ref] an element in array?

Tags: c#, powershell, pinvoke, powershell-core

I'm working on coding a P/Invoke using PowerShell Core, but it fails.

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Bindings
{
    [DllImport("MyEncoder.dll")]
    public static extern bool EncodeStream(
        byte[] pbIn,
        int cbIn,
        ref byte pbOut,
        out int cbOut);
}
```

My C# code is as:

```cs
var pbOut = new byte[pbIn.Length];
int cbOut = 0;
Bindings.EncodeStream(pbIn, pbIn.Length, ref pbOut[0], out cbOut);
```

It works.

My PowerShell code is as:

```
$Bindings = Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cs_code -PassThru

[byte[]]$pbIn = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("src.txt")
$cbIn = $pbIn.Length

$pbOut = [byte[]]::new($cbIn)
$cbOut = [int]0

# PowerShell 7.3.9
# Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
$Bindings::EncodeStream($pbIn, $cbIn, [ref]$pbOut[0], [ref]$cbOut)
```

I tried debugging and found `GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject` returned different address for `$pbOut` `$pbOut[0]`. So I wonder if it's the point that `$pbOut[0]` created new value and PoewrShell referenced the temp value instead.

Any help and test is welcome!

Comment: Since you already have C# code, why don't use inline C# with powershell (`Add-Type -Language CSharp @"my c# code"` like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7.3#example-1-add-a-net-type-to-a-session), I find it much easier than trying to understand Powershell funky .NET interop syntax

Comment: `ref byte pbOut` is wrong anyway, you should pass an array buffer with size.

Comment: @Charlieface I found this usage from disassembled code in dotPeek, it really works for `char*`. And yes we can use `byte[]` instead, I tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell's [`[ref]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSReference) *type* and C#'s `ref` *keyword* function very differently, and you fundamentally cannot obtain a reference to an individual array element in PowerShell.

To work around this limitation, create a C# *wrapper* method around your P/Invoke method, which:

- accepts a whole `byte[]` array from PowerShell and uses `ref pbOut[0]` *internally* in the P/Invoke call.
- for easier use from PowerShell:

  - *returns* the `cbOut` value
  - throws an *exception* if an error occurs.

Something along the following lines (untested):

```
$Bindings = Add-Type -PassThru @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Bindings
{
    public static int EncodeStream(byte[] pbIn, byte[] pbOut)
    {
      int cbOut;
      if (!EncodeStream_Impl(pbIn, pbIn.Length, ref pbOut[0], out cbOut)) 
      {
        throw new Exception("Encoding failed.");
      }
      return cbOut;
    }

    [DllImport("MyEncoder.dll", EntryPoint="EncodeStream")]
    private static extern bool EncodeStream_Impl(
        byte[] pbIn,
        int cbIn,
        ref byte pbOut,
        out int cbOut);
}
'@

[byte[]]$pbIn = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("src.txt")

$pbOut = [byte[]]::new($pbIn.Length)

$cbOut = $Bindings::EncodeStream($pbIn, $pbOut)
```